# Propositional atoms in first-order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

What are the different ways of, in effect, incorporating propositional atoms into first-order logic?

For instance: Halbach, in *The Logic Manual*, in effect makes $0$-place predicates serve as atoms, but then takes the semantic value of these predicates to be truth-values (whereas he takes the semantic value of an $n$-place predicate to be, as is usual, an $n$-place relation).

There are obviously other possibilities (though most of the other texts I've looked at don't have an equivalent for propositional atoms at all).  I'm looking for pointers to texts which have these other possibilities.

Comment: There is no discrepancy; the semantics gives denotation to terms (constants and complex terms made with function symbols) and truth value to formulas. A predicate symbol $P$ of arity $0$ is a formula (a sentence); thus its "meaning" according to the semantics will be a truth value. This is the same for others atomic formulas, like $x=x$ and $R_n(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$, where $R_n$ is an n-ary predicate symbol.

Comment: The semantic clause for $R_n$ will be : $[R_n(t_1,\ldots, t_n)]= \text {T (or: 1 ) iff } (t_1^M, \ldots, t_n^M) \in R_n^M$, where $M$ is the interpretation.

Comment: I didn't claim that there was a discrepancy, @MauroALLEGRANZA.  And of course there is no technical problem.  But I do think there is an awkwardness.  Of course, predicate symbols of arity 0 are also formulas, as you mention; and as formulas, they can be evaluated as true or false.  But they are also predicate symbols, and yet the clause for $R_n$ you give will only apply in the case where $n>0$ (Halbach himself just has a separate clause for predicates of arity 0).  To my mind, the conceptual awkwardness here would be removed by having a separate category of atoms in signatures for FOL.

Comment: The issue is that the interpretation of an atomic formula with a predicate symbol $R_n$ with $n > 0$ is defined "compositionally" from the interpretation of the predicate symbol **and** that of the $n$ terms filling the empty places in it. When $n=0$ we have no empty places and no terms filling them; but still the atom $P$ may be interpreted with a subset of the domain of $M$ (as in the case of $R_n$). We may say that $P^M= \emptyset$ when the int assigns False to $P$ and that $P^M= \text {Dom}(M)$ when the int assigns True to $P$.

Comment: Yes, this is one way to do it (not Halbach's, incidentally).  My question was about references to texts for the various different ways.  Do you have some for the method you've just described?

Comment: See e.g. [van Dalen](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~mlogica/livros/Logic%20and%20Structure%20-%20Van%20Dalen.pdf), page 61. And see [Kreisel & Krivine](https://www.irif.fr/~krivine/articles/Elements_logic.pdf) page 17 : for the interpretation with *domain* $E$, the formula $\top$ will be interpreted with the constant $E$ and $\bot$ with the constant $\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks, @MauroALLEGRANZA: those references are useful.